# VS2013: How to make PostBuildEvent depend on the chosen platform?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I need to copy some runtime files to the target directory according to CPU architecture (x64/x86). Note: I don't care about the architecture of the host machine itself, but the solution platform that I have chosen in Visual Studio.

What would be the correct variable to test?

Currently I have:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>
        copy "$(ProjectDir)\deps\x64\*.*" "$(TargetDir)"
    </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Simplest would be to just use the VS GUI to automatically generate what you need. Otherwise use @leppie suggestion below

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername `Build Events` cant be configured like that.

Comment: @leppie Why not? http://imgh.us/Untitled_578.png

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: That is not available for C#. Perhaps removing the `c#` tag was a mistake :)

Comment: @leppie Really? That's extremely weird. Why on earth would they limit it to language type...

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: Perhaps they assume .NET (users) do not have those requirements... I need it in some of my projects.

Comment: @leppie So why is it possible to achieve the same result by direct project file editing?

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: MSBuild supports it. I guess MS just deemed it too confusing for normal .NET users :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your platforms has been setup as `x64` and `x86`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x64'">
        copy "$(ProjectDir)\deps\x64\*.*" "$(TargetDir)"
    </PostBuildEvent>
    <PostBuildEvent Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'x86'">
        copy "$(ProjectDir)\deps\x86\*.*" "$(TargetDir)"
    </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Tip:** Look in the csproj file for what the platform choices are.

Comment: ...assuming it's C# project

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername: Question was tagged with C# originally :)

Comment: Yes, it's a C# project using a C library.

Comment: Couldn't it be done in one line, without the condition? Like that: `copy "$(ProjectDir)\deps\$(Platform)\*.*" "$(TargetDir)"` ?